# JAVA WOPI : What should be the return type of GetFileContent API?

Tags: java, ms-office, ms-wopi

I have successfully implemented JAVA WOPI Host with Microsoft's Office Online client under their **Office 365 Cloud Storage Partner Program** 
 Now I want to implement the same flow using Custom WOPI client (**Office Web Apps Server**). 
I am assuming there will be minimal changes in the wopi host code. Till now these are the things I have implemented :

- Deployed  [Office Web Apps Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219455.aspx) On Windows Server 2012 R2.
- Up WOPI Host
- GetFileInfo API is first API which should get invoke and yes it is getting invoke and I can see the JSON with proper values.
- GetFileContent API is also getting invoke just after the GetFileInfo API call but I can not see the file on the browser.

[image]

Below is the JAVA code snippet for get file content, I can see this method gets invoke and sending back the file content in byte streams but I can't see the file on browser.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{fileName}/contents")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getFileContent(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName,@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

    final String filePath = "C:/wopi-docs/"+fileName;
    File file = new File(filePath);

    byte[] content = null;
     try {  

        content = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);      

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)).build();
}
```

This is the same method which is working when we use it with Office Online but doesn't work with Office Web Apps Server.

Any input or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to edit? Word, Excel? You say you deployed OWA (not OOS) which needs COBALT for Word...this may be the reason. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062025/wopi-host-implementation-in-nodejs/39186295#39186295

Answer (score 1):

```
Optional<java.nio.file.Path> first = findFile(fileId);
        if (first.isPresent()) {
            return Response.ok(new File(first.get().toUri()), APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode(), "No file found with the " +
                    "name " + fileId).build();
        }

private Optional<java.nio.file.Path> findFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File filePath= getPath();

    try (Stream<java.nio.file.Path> stream = Files.find(filePath, 1, (path, attr) -> path.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().equals(fileName.toLowerCase()))) {
        return stream.findFirst();
    }
}
```

This code works for me. You can try this