# WOPI to use office 365

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, office365api, onedrive, ms-wopi

I want to use office 365 api to open and edit the documents stored on my server.
How can i upload files from my server to office 365 account without knowing to end user i.e. without asking the credential to end user. 
What i want to do is when there's any open request will upload that file to my office 365 business account and will open that in  office online or from office 365 api.

How can i achieve this from my asp.net MVC application.
Can i use WOPI here.
Any sample example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view or edit your Office files in a web browser, you should deploy an instance of Office Online Server (Office Web Apps) and implement a WOPI host.

You most certainly SHOULD NOT go the way you suggested - uploading documents to Office 365 via API and somehow figuring out their view/edit URLs. (In this case you wouldn't need to implement the WOPI workflow but it's total nonsense.)

If you need some .NET examples, check out my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281354/existing-wopi-hosts/45307368#45307368).

If you want to learn more about MS-WOPI and related protocols, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186295/1332034).