# Existing WOPI hosts?

Tags: android, ios, ms-office, ms-wopi

I'm about to implement my own WOPI host for viewing and editing Office documents on iOS and Android, but I was wondering if there are any existing solutions out there already?

Can I use SharePoint or OneDrive documents for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my little list of existing implementations:

- [petrsvihlik/WopiHost](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost)
- [OfficeDev/PnP-WOPI](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-WOPI)
- [Microsoft/Office-Online-Test-Tools-and-Documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Office-Online-Test-Tools-and-Documentation)
- [apulliam/WOPIFramework](https://github.com/apulliam/WOPIFramework)
- [Building an Office Web Apps (OWA) WOPI Host](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Building-an-Office-Web-f98650d6)
- [marx-yu/WopiHost](https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost)
- [thebitllc/WopiBasicEditor](https://github.com/thebitllc/WopiBasicEditor)
- [jacob-l/WopiHost](https://github.com/jacob-l/WopiHost)

Another list of resources can be found [here](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost#useful-resources).

The best resource, however, is the official documentation which has been refreshed not too long ago:

- https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/index.html

> Can I use SharePoint or OneDrive documents for example?

Yes, you can...that's all up to your WOPI host implementation. You can perhaps gain some inspiration [here](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost). This WOPI host has been designed with modularity in mind. 
You can easily extend it by implementing several [interfaces](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost/tree/master/WopiHost.Abstractions) (mainly the `IWopiStorageProvider`) and configuring the application to use your assembly as a default "storage provider".

Comment: you seem to be the only person I can find that has a real good handle on this.  If the WOPI host is, say, SharePoint, and the WOPI Client is Office Online Server, can I somehow use that client (Office Online) in an iFrame within our application?   We want to provide our clients who have the software a way to collaborate on documents within our application.

Comment: Yeah, it is possible (or at least used to be a couple of years ago with Office Web Apps). I've been a part of a project where the word/excel file editing functionality for a 3rd party app was achieved by uploading the file to SharePoint and generating an edit link for OWA+SP. This approach was cumbersome, to say the least, and it had many limitations and drawbacks. But it was cheap at that time. This motivated me to work on a proper WOPI implementation in my spare time (and leave that company :D)

Comment: If you plan to utilize just OOS/OWA from an existing SP deployment and communicate with it directly via WOPI, that's fine. But I'd strongly recommend against the approach described above.

Comment: Thanks for answering quickly!  It sounds like we'd have to do something funky, then, unless maybe we wrote our own WOPI server for our application? (docs are stored in database).  We are also considering just allowing them to create the document from a good HTML Editor then exporting from there, but it's dealing with the existing documents that becomes a problem.  Imports of any kind to HTML are far from perfect.